# create custom events in ext js inside if else loop

Tags: events, extjs, localhost

I am new to ext js. I am trying to create a custom event in ext js inside a if else loop. Is it possible to create events inside if else loop. Kindly help me...

Particularly I want to create it inside the else loop...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why you want custom events in if and else?Whats your requirment?

Comment: I want to call a method which is another js file using custom event